# How access to the router after changing his IP?

Tags: router, ip

After I have changed the IP of the router from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.2.1 , I can't access to the router from the browser when I type the new IP address.
How I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: did you restart your computer's network interface? What is the output of `ipconfig /all`if you are using windows or `ifconfig`if you are using linux. Usually the router configuration page is in the same address as the default GW.

Comment: The IPv4 is 192.168.2.141 and the default  GW is 192.168.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Opening a command prompt window and typing `ipconfig /renew` may work if your router provides DHCP service as is common with home routers and if your configuration changes didn't make the DHCP pool range inconsistent with the new IP address.